# Is there a way to stack sticky headers in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm having a table (two directional scroll) with a sticky header showing the title of columns. If it wouldn't support two directional scroll, I could just place the header outside of the scroll view, but it's not the case.

I want to implement grouping of rows (basically `SectionList` with `stickySectionHeadersEnabled`). There an upcoming section header replaces the previous section header, which is the expected behaviour for my case. However, I want to have two sticky headers stay in place (the table header, and the current section header). I couldn't find a way to set the `top` value for the sticky headers as in html:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.tableHeader, .sectionHeader {
  position: sticky;
}
.tableHeader {
  top: 0;
}
.sectionHeader {
  top: 20px;
}
.section {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.section:last-of-type {
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='tableHeader'>Table header</div>

  <div class='section'>
    <div class='sectionHeader'>Section header 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='section'>
    <div class='sectionHeader'>Section header 2</div>
  </div>
</div
```

Any way to earn the above in react native?

I was thinking about the implementation of nesting two `ScrollViews`, where the outer could be `horizontal`, and it could have the first child as the table header, and the second is the `SectionList`. It could work, but not being able to scroll diagonally is very annoying for me, had a hard time to implement it on ios, and wasn't even able to do it on android, so it would be a last case.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a FlatList with stickyHeaderIndices where the indices are the indices of the headers in your array.

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />;

    <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0, 6]}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
```

For the diagonal scroll, it should work on iOS with directionalLockEnabled set to false according to the docs but it doesn't.

For both ScrollViews to work on android the nestedScrollEnabled property should be set to true.

Here's a snack with an implementation, it doesn't seem to work on the web but it works on the iOS and android emulators:
https://snack.expo.dev/yyz6ro3Hi